# How can I assign a null value to a query param in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, null, param

I have a database table with an int column that can also be null. Adding an int to the column is fine, but setting it back to null causes an error. Since ColdFusion does not support null values, I usually pass the value as an empty string:

```
local.myParam = "";
```

This causes an error however, that `""` is not of type numeric.

```
post.addParam(name="parentId", cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER", value=arguments.parentId);
```

Any ideas how I can work around this limitation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the empty string to be sent as `null`, you can do something like this:

```
post.addParam(... null=len(trim(local.myParam)) ? false : true ...);
```

Which is to say, `<cfqueryparam>` and `addparam` support a `null` argument in addition to the others like `name` or `cfsqltype`. Setting `null` as `true` will provide the given value to the database as a proper null. For convenience, I'm using the ternary conditional operator to inline a true or false value. You could achieve the same thing, old-school, by using `iif()`.

Comment: thank you. Is null it's own argument here... so addParam(name="foo", null=len(...), cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER", value=arguments.parentId) ??

Comment: @Mohamad, yes, that's how it works. If the null argument evaluates to false, the rest of the `addParam()` works just as if it weren't there. If it's true, then the value is ignored in favor of null.

Comment: you might want to edit the answer to add a NOT condition, so: null=(! Len(arguments.foo)) ? true : false

Comment: @Mohamad, yes, I noticed that problem too. I switched the true and false rather than using `!` or `not`.

Comment: This answer doesn't match @Mohamad 's suggestion made on Feb 15 '11 at 18:00. It is still missing the ! in the expression.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want this...

```
null=yesNoFormat(NOT len(trim(local.myParam)))
```